# Why does `stats.mode()` function truncate the answer on an array of strings?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use scipy's `stats.mode` function to get the most common string out of an array of strings. But the function is truncating the strings for some reason.

```
>>> a
array([' State-gov', ' Self-emp-not-inc', ' Private', ..., ' Private',
       ' Private', ' Self-emp-inc'],
      dtype='|S27')

>>> stats.mode(a)
(array([' P'],
      dtype='|S2'), array([ 22696.]))
```

(The answer should be `' Private'`.) Any ideas how I can get the full string? And why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please show it getting the wrong string? I don't suppose any of your values are longer than 27 bytes? You appear to be asking `numpy` to create an array of string of length 27.

Comment: @holdenweb I have also encountered this bug/behavior before.

Comment: Its not getting the wrong string, its simply truncating the answer (which in that example is `' Private'`. And I haven't included the code where I create the array, in the first line I'm simply printing the array.

Comment: I just added a bug report for this - https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3814 - I didn't see it reported before. Pretty annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is/was happening because there was a bug in the implementation, where the results array was not being initialised with the same dtype as the input array. I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3857) to fix it which has been accepted so I suppose it will be fixed in scipy 1.9.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you can solve with `sp.stats.mode()` - I have also encountered this weird behavior before.

For a non-scipy solution you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
collections.Counter(a).most_common(1)
```

This will return a tuple with the string and its number of occurrences.

Comment: while at the same time only being related to 50% of the tags. Brilliant.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! But I'm still curious as to why `stats.mode` is behaving this way..